# Pandas - conditionally select column name based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

How to select column name based on column value of a DataFrame in python?
Many thanks,

```
import pandas as pd

foo = pd.DataFrame([['A',1,2,4],['B',3,4,2],['C',5,6,1]], columns=('a', 'x', 'y','z'))
foo.set_index('a')
Out[1]:

a  x  y  z

A  1  2  4

B  3  4  2

C  5  6  1
```

For each row, check the column values, if the value <= 2, record the column name.

For the above example,the output would like to be:

```
Output[2]: 

a  1  2  3

A  x  y  

B  z

C  z
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `melt` ,then filter the value , then `assign` a new key for the value by using `cumcount`

```
df=foo.melt('apple').\
        loc[lambda x : x.value<=2].\
          assign(value=lambda x : x.groupby('apple').cumcount()+1)


df.pivot('apple','value','variable')
Out[56]: 
value  1    2
apple        
A      x    y
B      z  NaN
C      z  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `mul` to replace values `<= 2` with column labels. Then sort to put empty strings at the end of each row.

```
import pandas as pd

foo = pd.DataFrame([['A',1,2,4],['B',3,4,2],['C',5,6,1]], columns=('apple', 'x', 'y','z'))

arr = (foo.iloc[:, 1:] <= 2).mul(foo.columns[1:].to_series(), axis=1)
arr_sorted = arr.apply(sorted, key=bool, reverse=True, axis=1).values

foo.iloc[:, 1:] = pd.DataFrame(arr_sorted.tolist(), columns=foo.columns[1:])

print(foo)

  apple  x  y z
0     A  x  y  
1     B  z     
2     C  z
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I test it, however, it gives an output which is not in your answer. the first row output is: 0  A  x  z  z

Comment: @Herry, See update, seems to work fine with a minor adjustment